# Check status of Meteor.js sync with server

Tags: meteor

meteor.js uses magic (ie: websockets) to sync the local db with the server. I have been searching for, but sofar have not been able to find, a way to see the status of the synchronisation. I would like the be able to check if a update for instance has been synced to the server. How could I do that?

thanks,

Paul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The callback associated with an insert/update/remove will be invoked with an `error` as its first argument. If `error` is defined, the server failed to make the modification. If it isn't defined, the modification succeeded.

```js
Comments.update(commentId, {$set: {message: newMessage}}, function(error) {
  if (error) {
    console.log('it failed!');
  } else {
    console.log('it worked!');
  }
});
```

Comment: David, thanks for your answer. The fact that this answer comes from you, lets me take it at face-value :-) Still, I would like to go a little further. I thought that minimongo acted like a local cache of documents. To be synced "at times" with the server. In my view, this meant that updates/inserts first happen locally, only "afterwards" to be synced to the server. This is then not correct? Otherwise the error would be a local error - not a server generated one...?

Comment: Your understanding is correct. A direct client-side modification will first update the local copy of the collection and then make the modification on the server. Only if the server rejects the modification will the client database be subsequently reverted. If it's important for you to know that the server-side modification worked, you should use the callback as shown above. This behavior is also described in the docs for [insert](https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/insert) and related functions.

Comment: It's worth noting that the client-side version could suceed and the server-side update could fail for any number of reasons including: (1) A [rule](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/deny) denying client-side updates, (2) A database error (e.g. a unique id conflict).

Comment: David, I accepted you answer - although it is not quite what I asked. Your code lets me see if there was a problem with the sync. But not /if the sync is still ongoing/. Is there any way to see that? :-) Or is Meteor supposed to be so very quick that the question should not arise?

Comment: I think we are confusing "synced" with "completed on the server". The callback says: "the server completed the update and did/didn't encounter errors". If you are doing a client-side operation (directly manipulating a collections - as above), the synced version should be identical to the local version anyway so in practice it shouldn't matter. Additionally, the change set will be sent when the callback runs so any delay would be network related, though often too small to notice.